# Ищу аналог GitHub, написанный на PHP

Tags: git, php, github

Собственно сабж. Ищу аналог GitHub, написанный на PHP. Существует ли такое?

Comment: Чем Вас gitlab не устроил ? [git-php](https://code.google.com/p/git-php/), но там все примитивно  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438163/web-interface-for-git-repositories

Comment: Третий день не получается поставить... Я не работал раньше с Руби

Comment: я тоже не работал, просто читал какие ошибки вылезают и гуглил или сам старался разобраться, почти все нашел на stackoverflow, ничего сложного нету

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю комплексное решение ваших проблем - готовый настроенный appliance (виртуальная машина) c gitlab-ом

Скачать можно на

- **bitnami**: http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab
- **turnkey**: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/gitlab